# Place Jquery error messages in a single box (or div)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation, jquery-validate

I have a jquery custom form validation as below;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var container = $('div.container');
    var validator = $("#form2").validate({
        errorContainer: container,
        errorLabelContainer: $(container),
        wrapper: 'li',
        meta: "validate"
    });
    $.validator.addMethod(
    "mydate",
    function(value, element) {
        return value.match(/^\d\d?\-\d\d?\-\d\d\d\d$/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy"
    );

});
```

I am using;

1. jquery-1.4.3.min.js, 2. jquery.validate.js, and 3. jquery.metadata.js

This validates my form `<form id="form2" method="post" action="">` and my form field

```
<input id="datepick" name="LDate" class=" {validate:{required:true,mydate : true }}"  style="width: 85px">
```

The empty error messages (required form field messages) are smartly displayed in a separate container as below;

```
<div class="container2">
        <label for="datepick" class="error">Please enter LDate</label>
</div>
```

, which is initially hidden from user using style

```
div.container2 {
  display: none
}
```

and will be visible on error.

The script checks the format of data entered in form field using jquery add methord. But my custom error message `"Please enter a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy"` is displayed next to the form field in a list format. I want to move this error message to the above `<div class="container2">`. How can I make this possible??

Thanks in advance.. :)

blasteralfred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for "addMethod" states for the optional "message" argument:

> message (Optional) String, Function
>   The default message to display for
>   this method. Can be a function created
>   by jQuery.validator.format(value).
>   When undefined, an already existing
>   message is used (handy for
>   localization), otherwise the
>   field-specific messages have to be
>   defined.

Try changing the line:

```
"Please enter a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy"
```

to:

```
function(){
    $('.container2).empty().text("Please enter a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy");
    return '';
}
```

I suspect this will do the trick, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Hi Neil :)
your code modified like `function(){
    $('div.container2').empty().text("Please enter date in the format dd-mm-yyyy");
    return '';
}` solved the problem.. Thank you... :)

Answer (score 0):

*First things first, make sure you are using firebug, it's css inspector is essential for this kind of thing. You can edit the css live on the page, tweaking positions and adding new properties till you get the css right, then copy and paste into your code.... Also make sure you have the firebug console enabled and visible.*

Use a combination of jquery and css:

**option 1:**
edit the plugin you're using so that container2 is inside container1. Set container1 to `position:relative;` and set container2 to `position:absolute;` and `top:-60px;` (you can then tweak top and left)

**option 2:**
Use jquery to get the position of the container1 div, `console.log($('container1').offset());`. You can then use jquery to set the container2 div's position above container one by subtracting say 60 from the offset and then using `$('container2').css({position: 'absolute', top: .....});`

hope this helps!